# Extract specific columns with condition from data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, extract

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| ID | Decision | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 2017-06-25 17:30:30 |
| 2 | no | 2017-06-15 17:32:30 |
| 2 | yes | 2017-06-15 17:30:30 |
| 2 | no | 2017-06-15 17:20:30 |
| 3 | no | 2017-06-22 17:30:30 |
| 3 | no | 2017-06-21 18:31:30 |
| 4 | no | 2017-05-25 17:30:30 |
| 4 | no | 2017-05-06 18:30:30 |
| 4 | yes | 2017-04-06 19:30:30 |
| 4 | no | 2017-04-07 13:30:30 |
| 5 | no | 2018-06-25 18:30:30 |
| 5 | no | 2018-06-25 19:30:30 |
| 5 | no | 2018-06-25 21:30:30 |

I need a code that groups by ID and filters like this:

- if decision is "yes" = extract this row
- if decision is "no" = extract the row with the latest time

So my new data frame should look like this:

| ID | Decision | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 2017-06-25 17:30:30 |
| 2 | yes | 2017-06-15 17:30:30 |
| 3 | no | 2017-06-22 17:30:30 |
| 4 | yes | 2017-04-06 19:30:30 |
| 5 | no | 2018-06-25 21:30:30 |

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be the following. For each `ID` sort the rows first by `Decision` (alphabetical, "yes" will come before "no" with `desc` and be prioritized; alternatively, one could order by factor level). Then sort by `Time` so rows with latest time are towards the top. Finally, `slice` and keep one row for that `ID`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(Decision), desc(Time)) %>%
  slice(1)
```

**Output**

```
    ID Decision Time               
  <int> <chr>    <dttm>             
1     1 yes      2017-06-25 17:30:30
2     2 yes      2017-06-15 17:30:30
3     3 no       2017-06-22 17:30:30
4     4 yes      2017-04-06 19:30:30
5     5 no       2018-06-25 21:30:30
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), Decision = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"), Time = structure(c(1498426230, 
1497562350, 1497562230, 1497561630, 1498167030, 1498084290, 1495747830, 
1494109830, 1491521430, 1491586230, 1529965830, 1529969430, 1529976630
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```